# Logstash is periodically hanging (unresponsive). How to recognize and fix?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

We are running logstash on Kubernetes. And some logstash Pods stops inserting data into ES for some unknown reason periodically (once in 2-7 days)

And logstash does not indicate there's something wrong with it. I mean the logstash process does not crash.The logs do not show any errors.

The only way I may know that the logstash stopped inserting data into ES is by looking into kibana and see no new data.

And restarting logstash is fixing the issue or after 2-4hrs it starts working normal again.

Has anyone had that kind of issues before? How can I identify whats causing this issue and fix it?

Logstash is receiving data from Filebeat for every `30sec` interval. It is receiving data from `~70 filebeat pods` and load-balancing enabled on filebeat logstash output section to distribute load across all logstash pods

`Logstash version - 7.6.2`
`pipeline.workers: 12`
`LS_JAVA_OPTS=" -Xmx4g -Xms4g"`
`Number of logstash pods - 8`

Comment: Do you use the api monitoring  with this kind of command ?

    curl -XGET 'localhost:9600/?pretty'

Comment: @YLR I see status as green when I check status using this command